# How can I sort the order of links based on the user's number of clicks and save it to local storage using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to add the feature to sort the order of links in a specific `div` based on the number of times a user clicked a link. It's to pin to top Favorite links of the user. It also has to be saved in `localStorage`...

For example, I have this:

```js
function clickCounter1() {
  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    if (localStorage.getItem(`clickcount1`)) {
      localStorage.setItem(`clickcount1`, Number(localStorage.getItem(`clickcount1`)) + 1);
    } else {
      localStorage.setItem(`clickcount1`, 1);
    }
    document.getElementById(`result1`).textContent = `Btn ABC: ` + localStorage.getItem(`clickcount1`);
  }
}

function clickCounter2() {
  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    if (localStorage.getItem(`clickcount2`)) {
      localStorage.setItem(`clickcount2`, Number(localStorage.getItem(`clickcount2`)) + 1);
    } else {
      localStorage.setItem(`clickcount2`, 1);
    }
    document.getElementById("result2").textContent = "Btn 123: " + localStorage.clickcount2;
  }
}

function clickCounter3() {
  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    if (localStorage.getItem(`clickcount3`)) {
      localStorage.setItem(`clickcount3`, Number(localStorage.getItem(`clickcount3`)) + 1);
    } else {
      localStorage.setItem(`clickcount3`, 1);
    }
    document.getElementById("result3").textContent = "Btn ZZZ: " + localStorage.clickcount3;
  }
}

function clickCounter4() {
  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    if (localStorage.getItem(`clickcount4`)) {
      localStorage.setItem(`clickcount4`, Number(localStorage.getItem(`clickcount4`)) + 1);
    } else {
      localStorage.setItem(`clickcount4`, 1);
    }
    document.getElementById("result4").textContent = "Btn ZZZ: " + localStorage.clickcount4;
  }
}

function clickCounter5() {
  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    if (localStorage.getItem(`clickcount5`)) {
      localStorage.setItem(`clickcount5`, Number(localStorage.getItem(`clickcount5`)) + 1);
    } else {
      localStorage.setItem(`clickcount5`, 1);
    }
    document.getElementById("result5").textContent = "Btn ZZZ: " + localStorage.clickcount5;
  }
}
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="links-list">
  <a href="#" id="one" onclick="clickCounter1()">A</a>
  <a href="#" id="two" onclick="clickCounter2()">B</a>
  <a href="#" id="three" onclick="clickCounter3()">C</a>
  <a href="#" id="four" onclick="clickCounter4()">D</a>
  <a href="#" id="five" onclick="clickCounter5()">E</a>
</div>

<br>

<div id="result1"></div>
<div id="result2"></div>
<div id="result3"></div>
<div id="result4"></div>
<div id="result5"></div>
```

If a user clicks `C` the most, it should be at the top.. I've been trying to search online but couldn't find such a solution for this.

Comment: have you tried doing click counting logic with localstorage?

Comment: Did u try to write any code? If yes then pls put it in the question

Comment: @ArchitGargi Hi I'm sorry I haven't written any script yet cause I really have no idea how I'd do it. I would prefer localStorage since it doesn't expire, but if I have no choice, cookies would be a good alternative..

Comment: You need to try something, start by adding click events: https://flaviocopes.com/how-to-add-event-listener-multiple-elements-javascript/ then work from there... This is nothing hard, make logic on how you will save in object in local storage ids of links with number of clicks that you calculate in click function... Task needs more focus, SO is not free script writing forum... You have 0 JS in your question...

Comment: Can you work your way through the problem with pseudo-code? Or a series of statements (again, not necessarily in code) that define the various steps that need to be solved? If you work out the individual stages, you may well be able to address your problem and make a start. When, or *if*, the eventual JavaScript has a problem, or doesn't meet your expectations, *that's* when you should come back to us and explain your problem, what you're trying to achieve, what you expected and what happened instead.

Comment: I'll help you with the steps: `1.` Add unique ids to links, `2.` Add click events, `3.` Add counting of clicks per id, `4.` Save that to object on every click `5.` Save that object to local storage on every click, `6.` Make a function that will rearrange the links in HTML based on object values, on load or on every click ... Research every step.

Comment: Thank you all for your tips.. I've updated my  question now to include some script for counter.. but I really don't know the next steps on how I will sort it.

Comment: yeah, this is wrong I'm afraid, no need to repeat yourself so many times in code, no need for function for every event or element... This can be done in short 2 or 3 functions. Just visit my link above on how to add events on multiple elements...  I'm going on lunch now, it's Easter. Maybe ill help later in the day if no one jumps in... Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The messy code below should work according to your needs. It stores the number of clicks in localStorage and reorder them according to it. I rewrote the click counter code because it is much more efficient and less repetitive.

*Note*: The below code won’t work in the snippet, because Stack Overflow doesn't allow localStorage in their snippets.

```js
function updateClicks(ele) {
  const storage = window.localStorage.getItem(ele.innerHTML + "Clicks");
  if (storage === null) {
    window.localStorage.setItem(ele.innerHTML + "Clicks", "1");
  } else {
    var clicks = parseInt(window.localStorage.getItem(ele.innerHTML + "Clicks")) + 1;
    localStorage.removeItem(ele.innerHTML + "Clicks");
    window.localStorage.setItem(ele.innerHTML + "Clicks", clicks);
  }
}

function orderItems() {
  var order = [];
  var href = [];
  var links = document.getElementById("links-list");
  var link = links.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (i = 0; i < link.length; i++) {
    href.push(link[i].href);
  }
  links = links.innerHTML.split("</a>");
  document.getElementById("links-list").innerHTML = "";
  for (i = 0; i < links.length - 1; i++) {
    var lastChar = links[i].charAt(links[i].length - 1);
    var clicks = parseInt(window.localStorage.getItem(lastChar + "Clicks"));
    if (isNaN(clicks)) {
      clicks = 0;
    }

    order.push([lastChar, clicks, href[i]]);
  }
  order.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a[1] - b[1]
  });
  order.reverse();
  console.log(order)
  for (i = 0; i < order.length; i++) {
                document.getElementById("links-list").innerHTML += "<a href='" + order[i][2] + "'  onclick='updateClicks(this)'>" + order[i][0] + "</a>";
  }
}
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="links-list">
  <a href="#" onclick="updateClicks(this)">A</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="updateClicks(this)">B</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="updateClicks(this)">C</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="updateClicks(this)">D</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="updateClicks(this)">E</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for taking the time to respond.. I tried copying the code above to a local html file, but it doesn't seem to work, there's also nothing in the console that I can check for errors.. Can you pls tell me if I'm copying it the wrong way?

Comment: @ixcode What is not working in it? The click counter or the reordering thingy?

Comment: sadly both feature doesn't seem to work, there's no record on the console logs for any activity if I click on the links. I maybe copying it the wrong way? I tried putting the script inside the `head` tags and also before the closing `body` tag but both ways doesn't work..

Comment: Oh I see now that it does store the count in localStorage, but it's not reordering the links, sorry about that

Comment: Oof I am so sorry. I forgot to tell you that you need to call `orderItems()` when the body loads.

Comment: It sorts the links now based on my previous clicks... but now that I've added `onload="orderItems();"`, it doesn't update the click counts anymore..

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution. Comments are inside:
fiddle to test: https://jsfiddle.net/ikiK_Cro/7cutpj20/7/

```js
// Create data for links in an array
let arr = [{
    id: 1,
    clicks: 0,
    text: "A",
    href: "#",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    clicks: 0,
    text: "B",
    href: "#",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    clicks: 0,
    text: "C",
    href: "#",
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    clicks: 0,
    text: "D",
    href: "#",
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    clicks: 0,
    text: "E",
    href: "#",
  },
];

const makeLIst = (data) => {
  // Get div for the list and empty it
  const list = document.querySelector("#links-list");
  list.innerHTML = "";

  // If localStorage exists with name "list", use that data.
  // If not, use the initial array.
  localStorage.list ?
    (data = JSON.parse(localStorage.list)) :
    (data = arr);

  // Sort data by the 'clicks' property
  data.sort((a, b) => b.clicks - a.clicks);

  // Create DOM, an href element for each link, and append to list div
  data.forEach((i) => {
    list.insertAdjacentHTML(
      "beforeend",
      '<a href="' + i.href + '" id="' + i.id + '" >' + i.text + "</a></br>"
    );
  });

  // Add an Event Listener on links
  document.querySelectorAll("#links-list a").forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener("click", (event) => {

      // Get the id and index of the clicked element in the data array
      const foundIndex = data.findIndex((x) => x.id == event.target.id);

      // Add a new click to it
      data[foundIndex].clicks = data[foundIndex].clicks + 1;

      // Save it
      localStorage.setItem("list", JSON.stringify(data));

      // Call this function again to apply the new sorted link
      makeLIst(data);
    });
  });
};

// Call on load
makeLIst(arr);
```

```html
<div id="links-list"></div>
```