# Need help on a todo list using javascript and local storage?

Tags: javascript

What do i add to my HTML and JS file in order to save values to local storage, and read them as well as load them from local storage so that they fill into the list automatically as well as adding a clear button for clearing local storage?

```js
let addToDoButton = document.getElementById('addToDo');
let toDoContainer = document.getElementById('toDoContainer');
let inputField = document.getElementById('inputField');


addToDoButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var paragraph = document.createElement('p');
    paragraph.classList.add('paragraph-styling');
    paragraph.innerText = inputField.value;
    toDoContainer.appendChild(paragraph);
    inputField.value = "";
    paragraph.addEventListener('click', function(){
        paragraph.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
        paragraph.style.color = "red";
    })
    paragraph.addEventListener('dblclick', function(){
        toDoContainer.removeChild(paragraph);
    })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>To Do List</title>
</head>

<body>
  <label><h1>To Do List</h1></label>
    <div class="container">
      <input id="inputField" type="text" name="todo" id="todo">
      <button id="addToDo">+</button>

      <div class="to-dos" id="toDoContainer">
      </div>
    </div>
  <script src="main.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You need to present a problem, try something and when you get stuck ask a specific question. here's some good read on local storage: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-localstorage/ Voting to close as there is no specific problem presented.

Comment: Also see this, I wrote that other day, you might get some ideas from it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71904912/7158959

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

> For some reason the snippet is not working. Kindly check out a working
> example here https://jsfiddle.net/rkhsxw0p/

```js
let toDoContainer = document.getElementById('toDoContainer');
let inputField    = document.getElementById('inputField');
let todos         = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos') ?? '[]');

function addTodos(){
    toDoContainer.innerHTML = todos.map((todo, index) => {
        return `<p class="${todo.done ? 'done' : ''}" data-index="${index}">
                    ${todo.title}
                    <button>x</button>
                </p>`
    }).join('');
}
document.getElementById('add-todo-form').addEventListener('submit', event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let title = inputField.value.trim();

    if( title ){
        todos.push({ title: title, done: false });
        inputField.value = "";
        localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todos));
        addTodos();
    }
});
toDoContainer.addEventListener('click', event => {
    if( event.target.tagName === 'P' ){
        let index = event.target.dataset.index;
        todos[index].done = !todos[index].done;
    }else if( event.target.tagName === 'BUTTON' ){
        let index = event.target.parentElement.dataset.index;
        todos.splice(index, 1);
    }

    localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todos));
    addTodos();
})

// load saved todo
addTodos();
```

```css
.done {
    color: red;
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <form id="add-todo-form" autocomplete="off">
        <input type="text" id="inputField">
        <button type="submit">+</button>
    </form>

    <div class="to-dos" id="toDoContainer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time buddy! You helped me out:)